# Анализ (обработка) двумерных сигналов

Tags: алгоритм

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите интересные книги, статьи или любые публикации про анализ (обработку) двумерных сигналов для линейного дальномера (лидара).

Необходимо найти технические алгоритмы обработки данных с лидара обнаружения препятствий и их преодоление исходя из показаний лидара.

Необходимо найти оптимальное построение траекторий объезда препятствий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Системы обработки многомерной дискретной информации](http://elib.spbstu.ru/dl/2066.pdf/view)

[Цифровая обработка многомерных сигналов](http://elib.spbstu.ru/dl/2/4688.pdf/info)

Не знаю, то ли это, но не могу не прорекламировать своего препода. У него были очень интересные лекции.